# Mark all stereocenters in ampicillin

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

Shouldn't the N pointed to by the red arrow also be a stereocenter? I am asking this because I think it's lone pair cannot take part in nitrogen inversion.

[image: ampicillin]

Comment: This is a very good question.  I'm not an expert at N stereochemistry but have you considered the iminol form of the amide/iminol tautomer?  It would have a double-bond to the N and would not be chiral.  I know the amide form predominates but if there is any contribution from the iminol it would "destroy" the chirality wouldn't it?

Comment: Why do you think that nitrogen inversion cannot take place there?

Comment: Probably because N is part of a ring but I am not sure if any strain is involved?

Comment: The two connected rings and the attached sterically demanding groups will certainly hinder inversion

Comment: Amide groups are flat! There's no point in talking about inversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the inputs from @Curt F., @PH13, @Martin and @Mithoron, I infer that N won't be involved in nitrogen inversion due to hindrance caused by connected rings and attached sterically demanding groups. Hence, 'N' pointed to by the red arrow will be considered as a stereocenter in ampicillin.

Comment: You didn't get my comment - it's flat so there can't be stereocenter!

Comment: @Mithoron Correct me if I am wrong, you said that amides are flat and therefore nitrogen inversion won't be possible, right? Now, the absence of nitrogen inversion facilitates in N being a stereocenter given that all the substituents attached to it are different as well (which is also satisfied in this particular case).

Comment: All substituents of N atom are in one plane - thats why speaking of prescence of inversion or lack of inversion doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Mithoron So, are you implying that a 3-D geometry is a requirement for an atom to be a stereocenter? Because I don't see it in any of the definintion of stereocenter I found on the internet. One of the legit sources being: http://www.chem.ucla.edu/harding/tutorials/stereochem/id_stereocenter.pdf

Comment: @Mithoron I think you should write up an answer. Also everyone please avoid extended discussions in comments. Use the chatroom instead.

Comment: @theprogrammer see discussion starting here http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23058334#23058334

Comment: I edited your answer - as you could see in discussion I linked the amide group won't be flat.

Comment: Oh yeah! I forgot to change that! Thanks bro. :)